# How do I apply rotations made using g2d.rotate to the x coordinates of a triangle?

Tags: java, project, graphics2d

I am attempting to create the functionality for a basic security camera in my game. The camera sits in the top right corner of the canvas, and displays a beam of light which rotates similar to a security camera (moves 90° in one direction, then 90° back). The functionality I am aiming for is that when the mouse is touching the beam, the console outputs "touching".

So far, I have the camera beam rotating using g2d.rotate, however the hit-detection does not move with the rotated canvas. I have tried a multitude of solutions, including the theorem used to move points of a polygon around one point, but the triangle kept decreasing in size with each rotation.

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Camera {

    private BufferedImage img;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private boolean moving = false;
    private double angle;
    private boolean up;
    private Graphics2D graphicsTemp;
    private AffineTransform at;
    private Polygon beam;
    private Point p1;
    private Point p2;
    private Point p3;
    private int[] xArray;
    private int[] yArray;

    public Camera(int x, int y, Point p1, Point p2, Point p3) {
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Camera.png"));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("NO IMAGE");
        }
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
        this.p3 = p3;
        angle = 0;
        up = true;
    }

    public void update() {
        xArray = new int[] { p1.x, p2.x, p3.x };
        yArray = new int[] { p1.y, p2.y, p3.y };
        beam = new Polygon(xArray, yArray, 3);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics2D g2d) {
        if (up) {
            angle += 0.2;
        } else {
            angle -= 0.2;
        }
        if (angle >= 90.0 || angle <= 0.0) {
            up = !up;
        }
        g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), p1.x, p1.y);
        g2d.setColor(color);
        g2d.fillPolygon(beam);
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.drawPolygon(beam);
        g2d.rotate(-Math.toRadians(angle), p1.x, p1.y);
    }

    public void testTouch(int mouseX, int mouseY) {
        if (beam.contains(mouseX, mouseY)) {
            System.out.println("INSIDE");
        } else {
            System.out.println("OUTSIDE");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't rotated the Polygon that you're doing hit testing on, so it will use the original unrotated beam for hit testing.

As a simple solution, you can rotate the polygon before you use it for hit testing. `Graphics2D` uses the AffineTransform class to do its rotations, and so can you:

```
public void testTouch(int mouseX, int mouseY) {
    AffineTransform transform = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(angle), p1.x, p1.y);
    Shape rotatedBeam = transform.createTransformedShape(beam);
    if (rotatedBeam.contains(mouseX, mouseY)) {
```

However you can also draw that rotated polygon directly in your `paint` method; it's better to rotate it once and use the rotated shape both for hit-testing and your paint method.

Note that it's also not a good idea to update your angle in the `paint` method since you don't know when and how often it is called. If your window was overlapped and then uncovered, your paint method will also be called.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I never really considered using createTransformedShape(), and then passing through the previous shape into a new form altogether. Brilliant!